# Обработка данных из сокета

Tags: python, сокет

данные из сокета получаются с помощью следующей функции:

```
def ip_connect(self):

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
    PORT = 12345       # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:
                print(123)
                request = conn.recv(1024)
                msg_size = 0
                if msg_size == 0:
                    if len(request) < 2:
                        pass
                    else:
                        len_message = int.from_bytes(request[:2], 'big')

                        if len(request) < len_message:
                            pass
                        else:
                            message = request[2:]
                            message = codecs.decode(message, 'UTF-8')
                            message = message[1 : -1]
                            msg_to_list = message.split(',')
                            data = []

                            for msg in msg_to_list:
                                msg = msg.split(':')
                                msg = msg[1][1:-1]
                                data.append(msg)
                                
                                msg_size == 0
```

Как только пришло сообщение, необходимо передать его в другую функцию, в которой оно будет обрабатываться. Я пробовал использовать `yield`, но не работает

Comment: где в вопросе видно, что вы пробовали?

Comment: Не совсем понял, зачем Вам `yield` (и не увидел его в Вашем коде, как правильно подметил @strawdog). Чтобы передать какое-то значение функции, традиционно используются скобки `название_функции(Ваше_значение1, Ваше_значение2, ...)` как-то так.